# Backup Azure website app settings

Tags: azure

I have an Azure website with a handful of app settings entries. These override those in web.config, the same as you would in IIS.

I'm using this feature to supply values to the app to avoid having them in web.config in the first place. This is to avoid committing sensitive info to a GitHub repo. Some are trivial/non-secret, and some are secret (like phone numbers, API keys, etc.).

Does Azure allow you to export these in anyway? I'd like to avoid copy/pasting them out.

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can get this using Site Control Manager (scm).  For example, if your website name is contoso, then open your browser to contoso.***scm***.azurewebsites.net.  Authenticate using the same credentials you use to access the Azure Management Portal.  This will land you in the "Kudu" default page where you will find a link to download app settings as a JSON file.

[image]

Click on that link and save it to your desired location.

[image]

You will get some additional environment settings as part of the JSON file, but you will also get all of your app settings.

If you're just wanting to back things up, you could also use Azure Website Backups.

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to restore these settings?

Comment: It seems it is more the app settings of scm than the app settings of the orginal web site.

Answer (score 2):

A useful tool is the [Azure Resource Explorer](https://resources.azure.com/).  The login for this is the same as your Azure subscription.

In there you can search for the name of your Web App, and drill down to the "appsettings" node.  There is more information on the tool [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-resource-explorer-a-new-tool-to-discover-the-azure-api/).

> subscriptions --> SubscriptionName --> resourceGroups --> ResourceGroupName --> providers --> Microsoft.Web --> sites --> WebAppName --> config --> appsettings

In the "appsettings" view, you can copy/paste JSON values.  Using this in combination with the Site Control Manager (scm) from the previous answer.  You can also use PowerShell to get/set these values.

The Resource Explorer page has been useful for me for setting up multiple environments (QA, TEST, STAGE, PROD) with similar configurations.